# Error when using Prisma with tRPC: Return type of exported function has or is using name 'prisma' from external module

Tags: typescript, backend, prisma, trpc.io

I'm trying to integrate Prisma with [tRPC](https://trpc.io/) for my backend. Both of them alone work fine but once I try to integrate them with each other an error is thrown.

This is the error message I get:

> TS4058: Return type of exported function has or is using name 'prisma' from external module "/Users/nils/Code/nextjs-coespace/node_modules/.prisma/client/index" but cannot be named

The file I get my Prisma client from:

```js
// Note! This file has been copied from:
// https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/typescript/rest-nextjs-api-routes-auth/lib/prisma.ts

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

// PrismaClient is attached to the `global` object in development to prevent
// exhausting your database connection limit.
//
// Learn more:
// https://pris.ly/d/help/next-js-best-practices

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-mutable-exports
let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```

My tRPC controller:

```js
import createRouter from '@/src/lib/server/trpc/routers/router';
import prisma from '@/src/lib/server/prisma';
import { z } from 'zod';

export default function locationRouter() {
  return createRouter()
    .mutation('create', {
      input: z.object({
        id: z.string().uuid(),
        // ...
      }),
      resolve(req) {
        return prisma.location.create({
          data: req.input,
        });
      },
    })
    .query('findMany', {
      resolve() {
          return prisma.location.findMany()
      },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's similar to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9944)

I had a similar problem, which I solved by displaying the statement

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes this is the issue. But I still couldn't solve it. Might you be able to post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `promise` that encapsulates `prisma` from your resolve, which means `prisma` is part of the return type, leading to the error message. The error message makes sense if you think about it.

The solution is to `await` the result explicitly, which leads to `prisma` *not* being in the resolve. You're still returning a promise of course, but that `await` prevents `prisma` from being exported with the `export type LocationRouter = typeof locationRouter`. If you hover on `resolve`, you'll see the signature is

```
(property) resolve: ProcedureResolver<unknown, undefined, trpc.InferLast<Promise<template[]> & {
    [prisma]: true;
}>>
```

The following fixes my error (and possibly yours):

```
  .query("findMany", {
    resolve: async () => {
      return await prisma.location.findMany()
    },
  })
```

With the await, the signature of `resolve` is now

```
(property) resolve: ProcedureResolver<unknown, undefined, template[]>
```

You will need to do this for every `resolve` that uses `prisma`.